# How to store hashed passwords on SQLite3 database?

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to store passwords on a sqlite3 database on python, however I don't want to store the passwords in plaintext for obvious reasons. I have used bcrypt to hash the passwords, but I keep running into issues.

```
import tkinter as tk
import bcrypt
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('TEST_DB.db')
c = conn.cursor()


class MainApplication():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.password_var = tk.StringVar()
        password_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=self.password_var)
        password_entry.pack()

        password = self.password_var.get()

        hashable_pw = bytes(password, encoding='utf-8')
        hashed_pw = bcrypt.hashpw(hashable_pw, bcrypt.gensalt())
        print(hashed_pw)

        c.execute("INSERT INTO Accounts (password) VALUES(?)", (hashed_pw,))
        conn.commit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    MainApplication(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Printing the hashed password yields the results I want

```
b'$2b$12$4SPZzQKBSKS1H1WHYRoC6.9pZTy1veZpc6x5MdM/LA1zgoKZWV6I.'
```

But when I insert that value into the database table, it shows in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O71a6.png) format.

Also, I have attempted to check the hash in the database against the plaintext password entered.

```
f = c.execute("SELECT password FROM Accounts WHERE user_ID=1")
        conn.commit()
        print("RETURNED HASH:", f)

        if bcrypt.checkpw(password, hashed_pw):
            print("It matches")
        else:
            print("Didn't match")
```

I believe based on how the format is shown in the database, there are some formatting issues involving that.

Here is the error message

```
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before checking
```

Updated to show database code

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('TEST_DB.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("""CREATE TABLE Accounts (
            user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            email_address NVARCHAR(320) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
            password CHAR(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
            )""")
conn.commit()
```

Comment: What's the column type in the database…? Your hash is binary, so either you make the column binary too, or you decode/encode it from/to ASCII getting it in and out of the database.

Comment: sorry, updated to show the database code. Regarding your solution, I have made the column BINARY(60), but it still displays the same way in the database as the screenshot I have above. (set of numbers, 30, 66, 98...)

Comment: Hello, this question is very well written, keep up the good work! To make it perfect, could you please just replace the image with plain text? It makes it easier for people to read.

Comment: The image is a screenshot from the  [SQLite DB Viewer website](https://inloop.github.io/sqlite-viewer/).

The plaintext of the password field is copied here:
`36,50,98,36,49,50,36,99,48,115,109,55,116,68,49,54,102,75,69,106,100,72,113,88,55,121,56,49,46,115,70,47,48,77,102,53,109,71,73,98,110,99,65,75,116,82,53,84,100,85,88,121,86,107,105,85,104,86,80,50`

Answer (score 1):

`password = self.password_var.get().encode("utf-8")`

This should resolve the issue.

Comment: You can use backticks `  ` to format your code.